# How to fix sound output device not recognized without rebooting on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio

Working with ubuntu 22.04 it seems sometimes after rebooting the sound output device is not recognized. In the setting I cannot select the output device connected to the laptop:

[image]

I reconnected the output device (USB headphones) and I ran the command

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

without success. The output device is still not recognized. I rebooted the laptop already twice.

I appreciate some idea how I can fix this issue without rebooting the laptop, while I reboot the laptop a third time now. Thanks

Output of `amixer -c 0 sget 'Master'` when sound is working:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

Output when the sound is not working and I need to reboot:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

The command `sudo dmesg -w` shows the following output when I plug in the headset when it is not working:

```
[  180.197897] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  182.938423] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  183.087660] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a45, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  183.087669] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  183.087672] usb 3-1: Product: Logitech USB Headset
[  183.087675] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  183.087678] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[  183.138531] usb 3-1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=496), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  183.138546] usb 3-1: [51] FU [Mic Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/7936/16
[  183.178269] usb 3-1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=1008), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  183.178281] usb 3-1: [49] FU [Headphone Playback Volume] ch = 2, val = -16129/-1/16
[  183.218532] usb 3-1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=496), cval->res is probably wrong.
[  183.218540] usb 3-1: [50] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/7936/16
[  183.220772] input: Logitech Logitech USB Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.3/0003:046D:0A45.0006/input/input34
[  183.278617] hid-generic 0003:046D:0A45.0006: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Logitech Logitech USB Headset] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
```

and the output of `pactl list short sinks` is:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

`/var/log/syslog` shows:

```
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.013612] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.162762] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a45, bcdDevice= 1.00
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.162771] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.162775] usb 3-1: Product: Logitech USB Headset
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.162777] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.162780] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.215929] usb 3-1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=496), cval->res is probably wrong.
Dec  5 06:36:03 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.215937] usb 3-1: [51] FU [Mic Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/7936/16
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.257716] usb 3-1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=1008), cval->res is probably wrong.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.257724] usb 3-1: [49] FU [Headphone Playback Volume] ch = 2, val = -16129/-1/16
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.297612] usb 3-1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=496), cval->res is probably wrong.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.297620] usb 3-1: [50] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/7936/16
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.299831] input: Logitech Logitech USB Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.3/0003:046D:0A45.0008/input/input36
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu kernel: [  386.358274] hid-generic 0003:046D:0A45.0008: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Logitech Logitech USB Headset] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6158]: 3-1:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6156]: 3-1:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6158]: 3-1:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6156]: 3-1:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6174]: 3-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6174]: 3-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6174]: 3-1:1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.3 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6174]: 3-1:1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.3 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6174]: 3-1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1 189:269' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[6174]: 3-1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1 189:269' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  5 06:36:04 alex-Ubuntu colord-sane: io/hpmud/musb.c 2101: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you show us `amixer -c 0 sget 'Master'`  please; for this command you need alsa-utils on your system.

Comment: See question ...

Comment: That is nice but I meant If Sound is not working.

Comment: I thought so. I will add the output when it is not working next time ...

Comment: @nobody I get the exact same output

Comment: When it happend the next time check `pactl list short sinks` if the state is suspended.

Comment: Maybe do `sudo dmesg -w` then plug your headphones in to see what system messages come up (again at a time when it's working vs. another time when not working) to see if that gives you any errors or clues.

Comment: Updated question with more details...

Comment: Maybe this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1968883