# How to fix USB headset not recognized anymore on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio

I am using ubuntu 22.04 and sometimes (very rarely) it happened that when I boot the dual-boot hp laptop to ubuntu that the extermal headset was not recognized. So I had to restart the laptop and it worked.

Today I restarted the laptop already 4 times and it never worked. See the other question [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492733/how-to-fix-sound-output-device-not-recognized-without-rebooting-on-ubuntu-22-04) for details. If that problem persists I cannot use Ubuntu any longer!

I ""guess"" that the following output of `/var/log/syslog` might be related to that issue:

```
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5139]: 3-1:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5141]: 3-1:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5139]: 3-1:1.1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5141]: 3-1:1.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5156]: 3-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5156]: 3-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5156]: 3-1:1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.3 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu systemd-udevd[5156]: 3-1:1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.3 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Dec 19 06:47:28 alex-Ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
```

I really need help on how to fix this issue. I will reboot the laptop until it is working again...

The workaround seems to be to boot in windows, then restart and boot ubuntu again. Good I still have windows 10 installed!